Get template name from variable and run template?
I have an Azure DevOps repository that I want to fill with a number of (pipeline-)templates.
Each template-file represents an Azure Container App Job.
On merge to production I would like the pipeline to identify changed templates and run these templates. The templates will then update/add Container App Jobs in my Container Environment.
If it can't be done this way what way would be better?
For clarification: I have a container ready that I want to start as multiple Azure Container Apps job with different parameters. I am not asking how to create a container in Container Registry.
Update:


Update 2:
First pipeline definition:
variables:
  ubuntuversion: 'ubuntu-22.04'
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main 
stages:
- stage: FindNewTemplates
  jobs:
  - job: FindNewTemplates
    pool:
      vmImage: $(ubuntuversion)
    steps:
    - checkout: self
      fetchDepth: 0

    - powershell: |
          $token = "$(system.accesstoken)" 
          $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))   
          $prefix_url = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
          $project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
          $buildId = $(Build.BuildId)
          $url = "${prefix_url}${project}/_apis/build/builds/${buildId}/changes?includeSourceChange=true&api-version=7.0"
          $response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}
          $changesCount = $response.count
          Write-Host "The count of commits associated with this build is $changesCount."


          $modifiedFiles= git diff HEAD HEAD~$changesCount --name-only
          echo $modifiedFiles 
          $modifiedFiles1 = @()
          foreach ($file in $modifiedFiles)
          {
            if ($file -like 'acaj-definitions/*tes*.yaml')
            {
              echo $file
              $modifiedFiles1= -join("$modifiedFiles1", ",", "$file")
            }
          }
          $modifiedFiles1 = $modifiedFiles1.TrimStart(",")
          echo $modifiedFiles1

          $url="${prefix_url}${project}/_apis/pipelines/14/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
          echo $url


          $JSON = "
          {

            `"resources`": {
              `"repositories`": {
                `"self`": {
                  `"ref`": `"refs/heads/main`"
                }
              }
            },
            `"templateParameters`": {
              `"files`":`"[$modifiedFiles1]`"
            },



          }"


          $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
          echo $response

Second pipeline definition:
parameters:
- name: files
  type: object
variables:
  ubuntuversion: 'ubuntu-22.04'
  acaj_memory: 4
trigger: none

jobs:
- ${{ each file in parameters.files }}:
  #- template: ${{file}}
  #  parameters:
  #    acaj_memory: $(acaj_memory)
  - script: echo ${{file}}

Update 3:
ADO output

Description  : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version      : 2.239.1
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
==============================================================================
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/usr/bin/pwsh -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -Command . '/home/vsts/work/_temp/b5f286c2-1c7d-41b0-b89a-c064e9581e64.ps1'
The count of commits associated with this build is 19.
.azure-pipelines/01_identify_new_templates.yaml
.azure-pipelines/01_identify_new_templatesmine.yaml
.azure-pipelines/02_run_new_templates.yaml
acaj-definitions/intralinks/testtemplate.yaml
acaj-definitions/intralinks/testtemplate.yaml
acaj-definitions/intralinks/testtemplate.yaml
https://dev.azure.com/companyname/projectname/_apis/pipelines/14/runs?api-version=5.1-preview

{

  "resources": {
    "repositories": {
      "self": {
        "ref": "refs/heads/main"
      }
    }
  },
  "templateParameters": {
    "files":"[acaj-definitions/intralinks/testtemplate.yaml]"
  }
}
Invoke-RestMethod: /home/vsts/work/_temp/b5f286c2-1c7d-41b0-b89a-c064e9581e64.ps1:49
Line |
  49 |  $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "B …
     |              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
     |  {   "$id": "1",   "innerException": null,   "message": "TF400898: An
     | Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id:
     | 647e4983-f3df-41eb-84e0-5d3b0f8bafaf.",   "typeName":
     | "System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib",   "typeKey":
     | "NullReferenceException",   "errorCode": 0,   "eventId": 0 }

##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Finishing: PowerShell



I am afraid that there is no out-of-box variable can contain the changed files information.

would like the pipeline to identify changed templates and run these templates

Based on your description, you are using the template in Pipeline to run the jobs.
We need to running the script to collect the changed files and send to the pipeline to confirm which templates to run.
Since the YAML templates will be expand at compile time and script run will execute at runtime, we need to create two Pipelines to achieve the requirement.
Here is an example:
Pipeline One: Used Rest API and Git command to collect the changed files and send the result to Pipeline Two.
Pipeline Two: Use Object type parameters and each expressions to loop the changed files to run the template.
parameters:
- name: files
  type: object


jobs:
- ${{ each file in parameters.files }}:
  - template: ${{file}}

Result:
Pipeline One:

Pipeline Two:

Update:
To let the Rest API to trigger the Pipeline successfully, you need to grant the Queue Builds permissions to two service accounts: Project Collection Build Service Account(OrganizationName) and ProjectName Build Service(Organization).
Click the Manage Security Option and set the permissions.
For example:

Then you can use the following updated Pipeline One sample:
steps:
- checkout: self
  fetchDepth: 0

- powershell: |
      $token = "$(system.accesstoken)" 
      $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($token)"))   
      $prefix_url = "$(System.CollectionUri)"
      $project = "$(System.TeamProject)"
      $buildId = $(Build.BuildId)
      $url = "${prefix_url}${project}/_apis/build/builds/${buildId}/changes?includeSourceChange=true&api-version=7.0"
      $response=Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"}
      $changesCount = $response.count
      Write-Host "The count of commits associated with this build is $changesCount."


      $modifiedFiles= git diff HEAD HEAD~$changesCount --name-only
      echo $modifiedFiles 
      $modifiedFiles1 = @()
      foreach ($file in $modifiedFiles)
      {
        if ($file -like 'tes*.yml')
        {
          echo $file
          $modifiedFiles1= -join("$modifiedFiles1", ",", "$file")
         }
      }
      $modifiedFiles1 = $modifiedFiles1.TrimStart(",")
      echo $modifiedFiles1

      $url="${prefix_url}${project}/_apis/pipelines/{Pipeline Two ID}/runs?api-version=5.1-preview"
      echo $url


      $JSON = "
      {

        `"resources`": {
          `"repositories`": {
            `"self`": {
              `"ref`": `"refs/heads/main`"
            }
          }
        },
        `"templateParameters`": {
          `"files`":`"[$modifiedFiles1]`"
        },



      }"


      $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url -Headers @{Authorization = "Basic $token"} -Method Post -Body $JSON -ContentType application/json
       echo $response

Or you can create a full scope PAT and use it in the $token field.
When the Rest Api runs successfully, it will return json object value.
For example:

Update2:
I have checked the YAML code. The cause of the issue is that the Second Pipeline YAML format has issue.
You can use the following format:
parameters:
- name: files
  type: object




jobs:
- ${{ each file in parameters.files }}:
  - job: 
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{file}}


Thank you for your help! While implementing it I got an error: parameter -Headers@ doesn't exist. Assuming it was a typo I added a space between -Headers  and @, which makes the first pipeline finish correctly, but the second pipeline isn't called.

@kiesel Can you check if the file paths are correct in the first pipeline powershell output?

And you can check if you have input the correct pipeline id of the second pipeline.

The files are absolute, from the root of the folder down to the files. The ID is the parameter ?definitionId=14 that I see in the browser, right? So in my case I used 14 in the first pipeline.

I just echoed the $response and noticed it contains javascript and a body, I assume that isn't correct?

@kiesel If you are using YAML pipeline, you should see the pipelineId=1302 in browser. If possible, can you share some screenshots about the current settings and the result?

Here is the doc about Rest API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-7.1

@kiesel I can reproduce your issue now. Please wait some minutes. I will find the solution.

@kiesel Please check the update in the answer. You need to grant the permissions to the service accounts or change to use PAT for authentication. Then it can work as expected. And you can try to use the updated sample in the updated answer. Feel free to let me know if it can work.

I added the requested rights but I am seeing the same as before (maybe the rights need time to sync?). I will try using a PAT on monday. I added pictures to my post to show what rights have been granted.

@kiesel The rights should be correct. Please use the updated code in my answer. I think that it will make some changes

@kiesel Is there any update about this ticket? Could you please try to use the YAML code in the updated answer to update your Pipeline?  Feel free to let me know if it can work for you.

I am actually just testing it. I got the rights sorted out, but I am getting this error now: {   "$id": "1",   "innerException": null,   "message": "TF400898: An      | Internal Error Occurred. Activity Id:      | 0f5b2a0b-9ac8-4219-a775-480d8871df26.",   "typeName":      | "System.NullReferenceException, mscorlib",   "typeKey":      | "NullReferenceException",   "errorCode": 0,   "eventId": 0 } when calling the second Invoke-RestMethod

@kiesel If possible, could you please update the question and share the two pipelines definition? You can hide the org and PAT information.

Updated. Thank you!

@kiesel  Let me test it. I will update as soon as possible.

@kiesel Please check the update2 in the answer. You can modify the second pipeline with the YAML sample.

Thank you! Unfortunately I am still seeing the exact same issue with the corrected code. I made sure (in ADO) that the pipeline was updated before retrying.

@kiesel can you share the output of the powershell task in the pipeline log?

Or you can try to create a new Pipeline with the existing YAML code and test again.

I added the output to the first post (added a few echo's). I'll try to recreate the pipelines.

@kiesel Thanks for your sharing. I checked the Pipeline log and I can confirm that the URL and Request body should be correct. It should trigger the Pipeline successfully. Please try to run it in new Pipeline and you can also try to change to use Windows agent to run the  Powershell script too.

It turns out the project build service also needs the permission Edit queue build configuration, otherwise (I assume) the files parameter is left empty which explains the Null Exception. Thank you VERY much for your help!!!

@kiesel Good Point! Glad to know that it can work now.
